# WebClient DownloadFile not working when download docx file with canvas from VSTS

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, docx

When I download .docx file that contains 'Drawing Canvas' from VSTS with WebClient then downloaded .docx document is broken.
When I said broken, I mean that we cannot manually open Word document and we have next error message:” The file is corrupt and cannot be opened”.

This is only happening if word file contains canvas and if is downloaded from VSTS ?!
If I download from TFS2017 or if .docx file does not contains Canvas than everything is working.

Firstly, I was thinking that issue is related to Encoding, so I tested all encodings that I’ve found inside of WebClient.
Making any change related to Encoding didn’t resolve current issue.

Also, I’ve tried to change implementation in a way that we don’t use method DownloadFile and instead of that, I downloaded array of bytes and based on bytes generated Word document.
With that change in implementation, we’ve the same issue as before.

This is code example:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tfsUri = new Uri("https://.../");
            var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri);
            var workItemStore = projectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
            var workItem = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(2);
            projectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
            var credentials = workItemStore.TeamProjectCollection.Credentials;
            var fileName = "D:\\test_folder\\files\\System.Description.docx";
            var uri = workItem.Attachments[0].Uri;
            using (var request = new WebClient() { Credentials = credentials })
            {
                request.DownloadFile(uri, fileName);
            }
        }
```

Thank you for your help if you have any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was not caused by the canvas in the docx file. The file should be corrupted even there is only text in your docx file if you download it from VSTS with your code.

The issue here is that the authentication to VSTS is different with TFS, so the WebClient download file request is actually getting 401 when download the file since it don't have required permission to download the file. Update your code to following and then try again:

```
    using System;
    using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
    using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
    using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy;
    using System.IO;

    namespace GetAdmin
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://xxx.visualstudio.com/"));
                ttpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
                WorkItemStore wistore = ttpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
                WorkItem wi = wistore.GetWorkItem(111);
                WorkItemServer wiserver = ttpc.GetService<WorkItemServer>();
                string tmppath = wiserver.DownloadFile(wi.Attachments[0].Id);
                string filename = @"D:\test\test.docx";
                File.Copy(tmppath,filename);
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful :)